# Writing a NON-EXIST query using JPA / Criteria

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm running an application simulates selling air plane tickets.
Using a simple schema (1-n):

```
SEAT
------
id_seat
description
position

BOOKING
---------
id
customer
id_seat
```

I'd like to produce a Query using either JPA API or Criteria which provides me a list of all available SEATs. That is, all SEAT Objects which do not exist (not booked) in the BOOKING table. (`SEAT.id_seat = BOOKING.id_seat`)

Can anybody give me a clue which is the best option to produce such a Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select seat from Seat seat 
where seat.id not in (
    select seat2.id from Booking booking 
    inner join booking.seat seat2)
```